# Can not get the shape attribute value of a dataset in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

You can check the following code,

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
tf.print(data)
```

The output is

```
<RangeDataset shapes: (), types: tf.int64>
```

The shape is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like python's `range`, `Dataset.range` also doesn't return the actual values. Instead it returns a generator-like object called `RangeDataset`. To get a numpy iterator you need `RangeDataset.as_numpy_iterator`. Then, you can convert it to a list, just like you would with `list(range(5))`:

```
>>> tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
<RangeDataset shapes: (), types: tf.int64>

>>> list(tf.data.Dataset.range(5).as_numpy_iterator())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> range(5)
range(0, 5)

>>> list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For more examples of its usage, you can see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#range)